# Does Craft CMS support 'encryption at rest' / 'data at rest' encryption?

Tags: security

Does Craft CMS support 'encryption at rest' / 'data at rest' encryption? I've looked [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/how-secure-is-craft-and-why-is-it-secure), [here](https://craftcms.com/support/topic/security), and [here](https://craftcms.com/support/securing-craft) - but can't find any info on this. Explain like I'm 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it does not. But this is typically something you'd do at the VPS level; examples of doing it on various platforms:

- [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/)
- [Linode](https://linode.com/docs/security/encryption/use-luks-for-full-disk-encryption/)
- [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/full-disk-encryption)

You could also do it at the database level as described here: [MySQL Data at Rest Encryption](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/04/08/mysql-data-at-rest-encryption/)