# Issues with Updating

Tags: updates, manual-updates

Is a backup needed before updating? Will installing new updates have any affect on the pages already saved or the existing structure?

Answer (score 1):

> Is a backup needed before updating?

It's definitely recommended.

Regardless of it is an [auto-update or a manual update](https://craftcms.com/docs/updating), Craft will attempt to perform a database backup if the [backupDbOnUpdate](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#backupDbOnUpdate) config setting is set to `true` (it is by default).

If that is set to `false` you'd want to perform your own backup before doing a Craft update.

> Will installing new updates have any affect on the pages already saved or the existing structure?

Updates should not make breaking changes to the front-end of your site.  The ones that do will be advertised as so, such as the Craft 2 => 3 update process.

You can see the steps that Craft goes through to make sure updating is done safely here: [How safe is auto-updating?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/how-safe-is-auto-updating)